# Python Time Series forecasting (sales volumes)

Tags: python, time-series, forecasting

I'm trying to make daily cash flow (inflow - outflow) prediction for the half year for a chain of stores. I have daily cash inflow and cash outflow for past 3 years, inflation rates, dates of national holidays and number of stores. Already processed data with pandas dataframe.

What Python tools (libraries, algorithms) will suit best for the forecast?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recomand to follow those steps:

- Find a correlation between dates and number of sales or any other variables (but i think date will do the trick people buy more stuff on holidays and weekends usually ) you can use the numpy library for that [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.corrcoef.html)
- assuming that the sales follows seasonal trends or weekends picks sales, you should compute those features based on dates you can add columns to your data frame such as dayofweek , season .. , pandas is great for that `dt.dayofweek` its as simple as that, split your data to train set and test set.
- Now cool stuff, you can try Linear regression using the sklearn [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html) i think it will work great! you can try other algorithm as well such as Ridge regression... alot of examples can be found on the sklearn web site http://scikit-learn.org
- Evaluate your model !

Comment: Thank you. I thought I would need something more specific for the time series, not the linear regression, also because there are season trends.

Comment: In my experience if you have season trends, linear regression work great have you tried any algorithms ? if so can you post some plots ?

Comment: not yet. Just googled and found recommendations to use NN. I'll try regression and see. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can look at [TSFresh](https://github.com/blue-yonder/tsfresh), that is a popular python library for extraction of features from time-series. Then you need to experiment with algorithms and the most popular python library for that is [Scikit-learn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/).

Comment: Will try and see, Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The common basic tools I would definitely suggest to import, represent and make basic (or not-so-basic) transformation and analysis are:

- [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org) providing "smart" data structures allowing to easily import data and perform many transformations
- [Jupyter](http://jupyter.org) to easily create notebooks integrating narrative text, code and results
- [matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/) for easy plotting of data (there is also a plot API in pandas which is based on it)

Specifically about time series forecasting I don't know much: you should be able to implement basic algorithms using pandas, otherwise example of useful libraries I found with a quick googling are [StatsModels](https://www.statsmodels.org/) and [Prophet](https://facebook.github.io/prophet/)

Comment: Thanks. All these tools: pandas, numpy and matplotlib are very good for arranging, preprocessing and plotting. But they are not suitable for making predictions.